# How To Change Screens By Pressing On Icons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am working on an app and have icons on the navigation bar and want the pages change when a user presses the icon but do have understand on how to do it in flutter. Here is an example, so I have the following code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 1),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        height: 70.0,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.chat_bubble,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.school,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.show_chart,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

and when Icon() is pressed I want the user to go to a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `onTap` of `CurvedNavigationBar` and in `body` call `pageChooser`

code snippet

```
  final Page1 page1 = Page1();
  final Page2 page2 = Page2();
  final Page3 page3 = Page3();
  final Page4 page4 = Page4();
  final Page5 page5 = Page5();

  Widget pageChooser(int page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 0:
        return page1;
      case 1:
        return page2;
      case 2:
        return page3;
      case 3:
        return page4;
      case 4:
        return page5;
    }
  }
...
onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _page = index;
      });
    },
  ),
  body: pageChooser(_page),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _page = 0;

  final Page1 page1 = Page1();
  final Page2 page2 = Page2();
  final Page3 page3 = Page3();
  final Page4 page4 = Page4();
  final Page5 page5 = Page5();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget pageChooser(int page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 0:
        return page1;
      case 1:
        return page2;
      case 2:
        return page3;
      case 3:
        return page4;
      case 4:
        return page5;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffF4F4F4),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Home",
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 1),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        height: 70.0,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.chat_bubble,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.school,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.show_chart,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _page = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: pageChooser(_page),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Page1");
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Page2");
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Page3");
  }
}

class Page4 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Page4");
  }
}

class Page5 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Page5");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case wrap your icon widget with.
`InkWell` and use `Navigtor.push() or Navigator.pushReplacemnt()`.
That should help I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you Just need to use onTap method in each BottomNavigationBar item as Follows:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new BottomNavigationBar(
    // showSelectedLabels: false,   // <-- HERE
    // showUnselectedLabels: false,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff38547C),
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    // showUnselectedLabels: false,
    currentIndex: 0, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: new Text(
          'Home',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("assets/images/ball.png"),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Matches',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.live_tv, color: Colors.white),
        title: new Text(
          'Live',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.poll, color: Colors.white),
        title: Text(
          'Ranking',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz, color: Colors.white),
        title: Text(
          'More',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    onTap: (int index) {
      var _index;
      setState(() => _index = index);
      if (_index == 0) {
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Home());
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      }
      else if (_index == 1) {
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Matches());
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      } else if (_index == 2) {
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Live());
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      } else if (_index == 3) {
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Ranking());
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      } else if (_index == 4) {
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new More());
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      }
    });
```

[image: Demo Screen]